# How can I add a *.hx file support in opengrok?

Tags: opengrok

I have a legacy C project which is using *.hx as a customized header file suffix. I'm trying to using opengrok to read the code. But it doesn't support this file extension.

I tried to modify the SUFFIX in
OpenGrok-0.12-stable\src\org\opensolaris\opengrok\analysis\c\CAnalyzerFactory.java

and compile to get the opengrok.jar
but it doesn't help.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to caching?  Have you tried removing existing databases?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [CLI options to opengrok.jar, especially the `-A` option](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/blob/master/src/org/opensolaris/opengrok/index/CommandLineOptions.java#L75).